# How to uninstall eclipse neon on ubuntu?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, uninstallation

I have downloaded Eclipse Neon from their official site and then I just ran an installer contained in the compressed folder(I didn't change any of the default installation settings). It is working just fine, but the icon in the sidebar is not displayed correctly when I am running it and the quick search from the sidebar also doesn't find eclipse when searched for. That is why I want to reinstall it, but i don't even know how to remove it completely. I tried Synaptic Packet Manager, but it doesn't work. What should I do?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse doesn't have a traditional install or uninstall process. Only a folder of an application is created plus the workspace which you created. If you used the Eclipse Installer, you may also have a bundle pool folder named **.p2** under your user home directory. There can also be .eclipse in your user home. Other than that, there shouldn't be anything Eclipse-related. Uninstalling is just removing those folders.